# Sending binary image data from PHP over ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, image

Let's say I've done the following in PHP:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('myImage.jpg);
```

Is there a way the image data from `$image` could be converted to a string that could be sent in my AJAX response?

Comment: What do you want to do with the response?  Do you want to display the image?  Have the user download it?  Based on what your final goal is, there could be a different solution.

Comment: move it to a folder and then send the path to it as a string in the ajax.

Comment: @RocketHazmat send it to an iOS app I'm building in Titanium so save locally.

Comment: @nathanhayfield I'd considered just sending a path instead... K.I.S.S.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work to get a base64-encoded string from the image:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('myImage.jpg');
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image);
$imagestring = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$encoded = base64_encode($imagestring);
?>
<pre><?php echo $encoded ?></pre>
<img src="data://image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $encoded ?>" alt="myImage" />
```

This will output the base64-encoded image as a string and will also display the image using that encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Use base64, or some other binary->text encoding schemes available, and pass it with the data in ajax, and decode at the client.

PHP has base64 functions, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php